# Error Domain=facebookErrDomain Code=10000 ,The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"; type = OAuthException;}}

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, facebook-oauth

I installed my iOS Facebook SDK and setup the facebook dashboard but when I clicked my already live app's facebook icon I get this error-

> Error Domain=facebookErrDomain Code=10000 "The operation couldn't be
>   completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)" UserInfo=0x16d74af0
>   {error={ code = 200; message = "#200) The user hasn't authorized the
>   application to perform this action"; type = OAuthException;}}

I don't really know if this is a code problem or a dashboard problem can anyone help me with this I? I am clueless

Comment: What action are you trying to do when that happens?

Comment: Did you try post something on user's behalf? I think you try to perform action, but not authorise permission before

Comment: On my game there is a Facebook Icon that you click once I logged in it and okayed it had this error popup. I think I got some help from the facebook developer community someone said it might be that I have to turn on the publishing_permission on facebook dashboard